# TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, словари

Функция возвращает

> TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

на строке `profile[symbol][j] = Probabilities[symbol][j] / t`. Почему?

```
Probabilities = {'A': 0.1, 'C': 0.1, 'G': 0.1, 'T': 0.1}

def Normalize(Probabilities):
    t = len(Probabilities)
    k = 1
    profile = {}
    for symbol in "ACGT":
        profile[symbol] = []
        for j in range(k):
             profile[symbol].append(0)
    for symbol in "ACGT":
        for j in range(k):
            profile[symbol][j] = Probabilities[symbol][j] / t
    return profile
print(Normalize(Probabilities))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__getitem__` метод реализует `seq[i]` операцию (обращение по индексу). `float` тип (числа с плавающей точкой) не поддерживают индексацию в Питоне.

У вас есть словарь `Probabilities`, который по заданному символу возвращает float. К примеру, `Probabilities['A']` возвращает `0.1`. Не ясно, что вы ожидали получить, пытаясь индексировать float: `(0.1)[j]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
type(Probabilities[symbol])
>>> <class 'float'>  # Probabilities[symbol][j]
```